# Adding JS to a form within Omega 4 theme

Tags: 7, forms, theming

I need to add some JavaScript to forms within my Omega 4 theme.  My code right now is:

```
function mytheme_preprocess_form(&$vars) {
    $vars['element']['#attached']['js'][] = 'path/to/myjs';
}
```

This isn't working, but it seems like it should.  I need to do this from my theme.  I don't want to use drupal_add_js(), since that's being deprecated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot do what you want to do in the form preprocessor.

Try using [hook_form_alter()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_form_alter/7) instead.

Keep reading for more information on why your current code doesn't work.

If you look at [drupal_render()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!common.inc/function/drupal_render/7) you can see that it runs this to theme the element:

```
if (isset($elements['#theme'])) {
  $elements['#children'] = theme($elements['#theme'], $elements);
}
```

This call to theme() is pretty much where your preprocess code code is running.

The output of that theme function ([theme_form()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!form.inc/function/theme_form/7) outputs a string of form markup) is then going into $elements['#children'].

Then further down in drupal_render() it does this:

```
if (!empty($elements['#attached'])) {
  drupal_process_attached($elements);
}
```

But the #attached code you added never ended up back in the $elements of the drupal_render() function though so nothing happened.

Comment: I can't do it (must do it in a theme for this project) in a module, unfortunately.  I figured if I could call drupal_add_js() in my preprocess fx, then I could use #attached somehow.  I guess I'll use drupal_add_js(), and just comment that I know I shouldn't use it, but hopefully Drupal 8 will let us do this in the theme with #attached.

Comment: I'm now wondering if I can do this in an Omega theme function...

Comment: @vintorg you can use a form alter in template.php (though it should only do _themey_ things)

Answer (score 1):

You can specify it in the .info file of your theme using
   `scripts[] = 'path/to/myjs'`

Comment: Yes, but I don't want to include this JS on every page.